# Redis get DISTINCT keys using scan command

Tags: redis, nosql

Using Redis scan command how do i get DISTINCT keys like below.

Data

```
hmset user_101_1 .. .. .. ..
hmset user_102_2 .. .. .. ..
hmset user_102_3 .. .. .. ..
hmset user_101_4 .. .. .. ..
hmset user_103_5 .. .. .. ..
```

Expected Result

```
user_101_1
user_102_2
user_103_5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't - quoting from [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees)'s documentation section about its guarantees:

> A given element may be returned multiple times. It is up to the application to handle the case of duplicated elements...